Creation external part table - invalid identifier
I want to create an external part table. I follow the Oracle documentation correctly but i have an error with my partition columns.
BEGIN
DBMS_CLOUD.CREATE_EXTERNAL_PART_TABLE(
TABLE_NAME => 'SERVICE_NOW_TABLE_PROBLEM',
CREDENTIAL_NAME => 'DEBUG_CRED_NAME',
FILE_URI_LIST => 'https://.../b/Bucket-DEV-DEBUG2/o/TABLE/*SERVICE_NOW_TABLE_PROBLEM*.parquet',
FORMAT => '{"type":"parquet", "schema": "first",
            "partition_columns": [{"name":"fetch_year","type":"varchar2(100)"},                     
                                  {"name":"fetch_month","type":"varchar2(100)"},  
                                  {"name":"fetch_day","type":"varchar2(100)"}]}'
);
END;

Here are the errors :

ORA-20000: ORA-00904:  : identificateur non valide
ORA-06512: à "C##CLOUD$SERVICE.DBMS_CLOUD$PDBCS_240705_0", ligne 2078
ORA-06512: à "C##CLOUD$SERVICE.DBMS_CLOUD$PDBCS_240705_0", ligne 10959
ORA-06512: à ligne 2
20000. 00000 -  "%s"
*Cause:    The stored procedure 'raise_application_error' was called which causes this error to be generated.
*Action:   Correct the problem as described in the error message or contact the application administrator or DBA for more information.

I tried a different form with my request but I still have the same problem.
The problem is with the partition columns because when I try to create an external table it works.
If someone can help me about this error please.
Thanks
